# Double opposite histogram in ggplot

Tags: r

I would like to know how to do this kind of graphs using ggplot :

https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/21/3/1558514850-plot-example2.png

This is an excel graph. I already know how to do each of the two histogram (left and right) but I don't know how to plot the two of them on the same graph, separated on the middle of the graph, with this duality.

Maybe using a specific package or geom I don't know yet ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build your histogram with `geom_col()`, to have positive values for one groupe, négative values for the second groupe, and then use `coord_split()`